# How should I approach the database logic behind a "forget this" feature?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So, let's say I have a `users` table and a `pages` table. Let's say that I want to allow users to hide/forget/ignore certain pages. At this point, I can think of two possible approaches:

### An outer join with `null` matching:

I can create a separate `ignored_pages` table with columns `user_id` and `page_id`, writing to it `INSERT INTO ignored_pages (user_id, page_id) VALUES (1,2);` when the user with ID of 1 ignores a page with ID of 2.

Then I can run something like `SELECT pages.* FROM pages LEFT OUTER JOIN ignored_pages ON pages.id = ignored_pages.page_id WHERE ignored_pages.user_id = 1 AND ignored_pages.id IS NULL;`

**EDIT:** [Joe Stefanelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341251/joe-stefanelli) pointed on an error in my query. It should be `SELECT pages.* FROM pages LEFT OUTER JOIN ignored_pages ON pages.id = ignored_pages.page_id AND ignored_pages.user_id = 1 WHERE ignored_pages.id IS NULL;`

### A subquery and `NOT IN`:

I can use the same many-to-many table and then run something like `SELECT pages.* FROM pages WHERE page_id NOT IN (SELECT page_id FROM ignored_pages WHERE user_id = 1);`.

---

Is there a best practice or series of rules of thumb or (likely) a better approach to this problem than the one I'm taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best performance may actually be a `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT p.* 
    FROM pages p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                         FROM ignored_pages 
                         WHERE user_id = 1 
                             AND page_id = p.id);
```

If you decide to stick with your `LEFT JOIN` option, you'll need to correct that query to test `user_id` on the join condition rather than the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT pages.* 
    FROM pages 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ignored_pages 
            ON pages.id = ignored_pages.page_id 
                AND ignored_pages.user_id = 1 
    WHERE ignored_pages.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I know he is asking for Postgre based on tags, but in SQL Server `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` are the same query plan in 2008.

Comment: I can't say I've ever used `NOT EXISTS` before, although I have to say it's a bit weird to wrap my head around its semantic meaning. I will sort it out on my own. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @JNK: See [this article](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/) for some additional discussion on the topic for SQL Server.

Comment: @JNK Actually it depends on the data and if null values are present or not.

Answer (score 1):

For best performance you should use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT pages.* 
FROM pages
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT NULL
   FROM ignored_pages
   WHERE user_id = 1 AND ignored_pages.page_id = pages.page_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also check the link http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/

Comment: tl;dr: That article says that Postgres generates the same query plan for the `left join` and `not exists` versions, so the only difference is style. I for one prefer the `left join`, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/) has a good comparison of using LEFT OUTER JOIN vs NOT EXISTS. A [related link](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/) on that page shows that NOT EXISTS is either comparable, or faster than NOT IN, at least for the example case on that blog. The first link shows that NOT EXISTS performs almost two times better (cpu cycles, and execution time) than LEFT OUTER JOIN, so long as you have an index on all of the columns being joined/matched on.

The index for ignored_pages would likely look something like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Ignored_Pages ON ignored_pages (user_id, page_id);
```

Adapting to your code, the NOT EXISTS syntax would look something like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM pages p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM ignored_pages i
   WHERE i.user_id = @user_id
   AND i.page_id = p.page_id
);
```

Comment: Missed the PSTGRE tag, and incorrectly assumed this was TSQL.